# Show kernel of action is a subgroup of G if G acts on A

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, group-actions

I've got a question about this:
`Show kernel of action is a subgroup of G if G acts on A`

I put the solution below after some definitions which are used in the solution and also my question.

**DEFINITIONS**

A binary operation $\star$ on a set G is a function $\star : G$x$G \to G$. For any $a,b \in G$ we write $a \star b$ for $\star (a,b)$

Group denoted $(G,\star)$ is an ordered pair  where $G$ is a set and $\star$ is a binary operation on $G$ satisfying axioms i,ii,iii: associativity, identity and inverse.

Group action is a map $G$x$A \to A$  denoted $g.a$ such that $g_{1}.(g_{2}.a)=(g_{1}g_{2}).a$  and $1.a=a$

`$.$` is not a binary operation and $ga$ is always a member of A

Kernel of action K = $\{ g \in G | ga=a \}$

**SOLUTION TO PROBLEM**

*Show kernel of action is a subgroup of G if G acts on A*

> $1 \in K$ since $1.a=a$ for all $a \in A$
>
> Suppose $k_{1},k_{2} \in K$ and Let $a \in A$
>
> $\Rightarrow (k_{1}k_{2}).a=k_{1}.(k_{2}.a)=k_{1}.a=a$
>
> $\Rightarrow k_{1},k_{2} \in K$
>
> Now let $k \in K $ and $a \in A$
>
> $\Rightarrow k^{-1}.a=k^{-1}.(k.a) = (k^{-1}.k).a = 1.a = a$
> $\Rightarrow k^{-1} \in K$
> $\Rightarrow K$ is a subgroup of $G$

**QUESTION**

This is where my confusion lies.

$k^{-1}.(k.a) = (k^{-1}.k).a$

I understand that this "associativity" applies to groups by axiom (i) but we already stated that `.` is not a binary operation.   So how can we utilize this associativity alongside the `.`  operator/operands, as in this line?

Comment: $g.(h.a) = (gh).a$, where $gh$ is multiplication in $G$. So the line you wrote in your question is not what you meant, I think. Try $k^{-1}.(k.a) = (k^{-1}k).a = 1.a = a$.

Comment: @rogerl Thank you.  That answers my question.  (very quickly..)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simpler approach.

An action of $G$ on $A$ induces a group homomorphism $G \to Sym(A)$ (and vice-versa).

The kernel of the action is exactly the kernel of this homomorphism and so is a (normal) subgroup of $G$.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  I will consider this once I study normal subgroups.